# Tweaking JFreeChart in iReports

Tags: java, jfreechart, ireport

I am using iReports with my web application where i render charts using the data available and export the document as pdf.

Now there is a point where i need to include some other details which are not possible from iReport so i was wondering is there a way, where i can configure iReport to use a customized jFreeChart??

Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are ChartCustomizer for ireport which you can try.

here is the link http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/
Its all about trial and error.

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can set custom version of JFreeChart directly in iReport. However if you manage to compile your own version of JFreeChart you can swap it inside iReport lib directory.